# Regular expression for custom period format (+/-, number, letter)

Tags: regex, expression

I need a regular expression to validate an input that must start with + or - sign, then any positive number, and must end in letters d or m (the value is used to specify periods ahead or before a certain date, like -3d means 3 days before, +2m means 2 months after, etc)

Thanks in advance

Comment: any whole number? or decimals too? do you need to support commas and periods? what about the thousands separator? what language is running this regex? javascript? mySQL? Java? PHP? Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[+-][1-9][0-9]*[dm]$
```

Matches a `+` or a `-` sign followed by any number (except `0`) followed by `d` or `m`. `^` and `$` are called anchors and they match start and end of string respectively.

Comment: Good one, you may want to add `^` and `$` also

Comment: Worked like a charm, very nicely explained too.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this regex pattern:

```
[-+]\d+[dm]
```

"-" or "+"
one or more digits
"d" or "m"

also you can group results:

```
([-+])(\d+)([dm])
```